# Tcolorbox breakable with different styles and rounded corners

Tags: tcolorbox

Let's take the following MWE:

```
\begin{tcolorbox}[title=Remark,arc=10pt,breakable,drop lifted shadow,
    skin=enhancedlast,
    skin first is subskin of={enhancedfirst}{arc=10pt,no shadow},
    skin middle is subskin of={enhancedmiddle}{arc=10pt,no shadow},
    skin last is subskin of={enhancedlast}{arc=10pt,drop lifted shadow}]
    \lipsum[2-4]
\end{tcolorbox}
```

If it breaks across two pages, i have the perfect expected result, ie:

- Rounded corners everywhere (top and bottom of the box)
- Shadow only on the second part

But if it doesn't break across two pages, i don't have the rounded corners on the top of the first part of the tcolorbox (at least on my laptop...).

Any help or advice?

Thanks for your  help

Comment: Use `skin=enhanced` instead of `skin=enhancedlast`.

Comment: Thanks! Your answer solved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

> But if it doesn't break across two pages, i don't have the rounded corners on the top of the first part of the tcolorbox (at least on my laptop...).

It's caused by `skin=enhancedlast` (note the `last` in key value `enhancedlast`). Using `skin=enhanced` will solve the problem.